# Possible to prevent access to /tmp for a specific user via SELinux?

Tags: centos, selinux

I'm sort of learning the edges of SELinux and I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent a specific user from accessing /tmp.

Clearly it's a bad idea to dork all permissions, so I'm hoping that SELinux can maybe target or restrict a little more precisely than just banning all users.

**Additional Information**

There is a process that has it's own internal temp space, but under "other" circumstances will try to write to /tmp.  I'd rather the process explode and die horribly than actually dump to /tmp since it causes all manner of other problems.  -- yeah, clear as mud, right?

For clarification, the data written isn't confidential, but also has no place on the server.  If it were possible I'd just dump it to /dev/null but that seems less than reasonable.

**References**

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/97b64f73103b/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp (about line 1624) (source inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir)

Comment: Maybe, but it might not be the _best_ way. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you want to restrict them?  If it's to protect sensitive/confidential information then it shouldn't be written to `/tmp`.

Comment: Does the application honor the $TMPDIR environment variable?

Comment: Please define/describe what application program you are dealing with.

Comment: It's a JVM based application running under OpenJDK 7.

I don't think it honors TMPDIR or Environmental redirects (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/97b64f73103b/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp about line 1624)

Comment: what context does the process run under ?

Comment: `ps -eZ` reports `unconfined_u:unconfined_r` for the process.

Comment: Maybe you could run your application in some kind of sandbox environment like [docker](http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/Docker).